# linux DD-MON-YY format in bash script

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

Is there any way to store `DD-MON-YY` ( for eg: 13-JAN-15) format date in to a variable

I know

```
datevar=$(date '+%d-%m-%y')
echo $datevar
```

will display `13-01-15`

Is there any way to display `13-JAN-15`

Answer (score 7):

This does exactly what you want:

```
date '+%d-%^b-%y'
```

Note the `^` before the `b` which tells `date` to print the month in upper case.

Comment: I didn't know about `^` in `%^b`. +1 :)

Comment: thanks a lot ... datevar=$(date '+%d-%^b-%y') worked